# Django AttributeError: 'GeoQuerySet' object has no attribute 'extent'

Tags: python, django, geo, django-1.10

My django code is broken and raises the following `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'GeoQuerySet' object has no attribute 'extent'
```

In my code I try to call extent on a django `geoqueryset`:

```
    if raster and bbox:
        self.extent = qs.extent()
```

My Django version is currently 1.10 and has recently been upgraded from Django 1.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Django [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#s-extent) the `extent` method on `GeoQuerySet`s since Django version 1.8. This can be fixed using the `Extent` [Aggregate Function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#s-aggregate-functions) like so:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import Extent   

# ...

    if raster and bbox:
        self.extent = qs.aggregate(Extent('geometry')).get(
            'geometry__extent')
```